# How to correlate columns from two different dataframes with datetimeindex

Tags: pandas, datetimeindex

I am trying to correlate the same column in two different dataframes (same size).  The dfs use stock data with a datetimeindex.  Every possible correlation I can come up with only gives NaN for an answer.  Is the dtype of the df indees messing things up?  Note:  at this point in the program, I don't care what the dates / index actually are.

input:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like # temp fix

import numpy as np
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

from pandas_datareader import data, wb
from datetime import date

df1 = yf.download('IBM', start = date (2000, 1, 3), end = date (2000, 1, 5), progress = False)
df2 = yf.download('IBM', start = date (2000, 1, 6), end = date (2000, 1, 10), progress = False)

print (df1)
print (df2)
print (df1['Open'].corr(df2['Open']))
```

output:

```
                Open    High      Low     Close  Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                
2000-01-03  112.4375  116.00  111.875  116.0000  81.096031  10347700
2000-01-04  114.0000  114.50  110.875  112.0625  78.343300   8227800
2000-01-05  112.9375  119.75  112.125  116.0000  81.096031  12733200
              Open      High      Low  Close  Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                             
2000-01-06  118.00  118.9375  113.500  114.0  79.697784   7971900
2000-01-07  117.25  117.9375  110.625  113.5  79.348267  11856700
2000-01-10  117.25  119.3750  115.375  118.0  82.494217   8540500
nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexes are not matching, that's why you get `nan` I believe. Use `numpy.corrcoef` on the raw values to get your result:

```
np.corrcoef(df1['Open'].values,df2['Open'].values)
```

#### Output

```
[[ 1.         -0.74615579]
 [-0.74615579  1.        ]]
```

Comment: thanks yuca, that worked perfectly.  can you tell me how to pull out the "-0.746..." number from the matrix, that is all I need.

Comment: sure, either do `np.corrcoef(df1['Open'].values,df2['Open'].values)[0, 1]` or `np.corrcoef(df1['Open'].values,df2['Open'].values)[1, 0]`